# sql query for checking each record insertion time in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:
select * from UserMaster_tbl my output like this:[image]

i want to check each record insertion time ,if can how i can show the insertion time as last column of this result

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to include a new DateTime field in this table with the information you need.

If you don't want to modify this table, i'd suggest you to create a new table with 2 fields:

uid => UserMaster_tbl Pk,

insertionTime => DateTime

You could create a Trigger related to insert in UserMater_table, and each time there is a new insert you create a new record in the new table.

Comment: But this won't work for previously added rows.